# function to check if a string contains all elements of another string

Tags: python, string

I need to write a function that takes two string arguments, and returns TRUE if the characters of the second string exist in the first one, else returns FALSE. For example: given `str1 = 'xBxxAxxCxxAxCxxBxxxAxCxBxxxAxxBxCx'` and `str2 = "ABC"`, returns `TRUE` (`str2 = "ABCD"`, returns `FALSE`).

I tried different variations of code and cannot get the correct one. I have the following code here where I used `in` built in function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
def minSubStr(str1, str2):
    str1 = input("Enter the first string: ")
    str2 = input("Enter the second string to check if the characters exist in the first string: ")
    if str2 in str1: 
        return True
    else:
        return False
minSubStr(str1, str2)
```

Comment: `if …: return True else: return False` can / **should** always be rewritten as `return …`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str2 in str1` check whether the whole string `str2` is present as a substring in `str1`. You need to iterate over `str2` to check if every character of `str2` is present in `str1` using the [**`all()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function.

```
def minSubStr(str1, str2):
    str1 = input("Enter the first string: ")
    str2 = input("Enter the second string to check if the characters exist in the first string: ")
    if all(s in str1 for s in str2):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: How can I modify minSubStr function to return the first possible substring (traversing from left) containing all the elements of str2. For example: given str1 = 'xBxxAxxCxxAxCxxBxxxAxCxBxxxAxxBxCx' and str2 = "ABC", the function to return "BxxAxxC"

Comment: @Py.learner you should ask a separate question for this.

Answer (score 1):

A really concise solution is to do the set difference between the characters in the two strings. The set difference will be empty if your condition is met:

```
return len(set(str2)-set(str1))==0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out, you need define `str1` and `str2` prior to calling the function

```
def minSubStr(str1, str2):
    if str2 in str1: 
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
str1 = input("Enter the first string: ")
str2 = input("Enter the second string to check if the characters exist in the first string: ")
minSubStr(str1, str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can optimise the iterations by using set in python.

```
def minSubStr(str1, str2):
    str1 = set(input("Enter the first string: "))
    str2 = set(input("Enter the second string to check if the characters exist in the first string: "))
    if all(s in str1 for s in str2):: 
        return True
    else:
        return False
minSubStr(str1, str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to loop through the characters
for example:

```
for i in str1:
    if str2 in str1: 
        return True
    else:
        return False
minSubStr(str1, str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method to check if the string contains all the elements of another string with the help of `functools` and `operator` libraries.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_, or_, contains
def containsAll(str1, str2):
    return reduce(and_, map(contains, len(str2)*[str1], str2))
str1 = input("Enter the first string:")
str2 = input("Enter the second string to check if all characters exist:")
containsAll(str1,str2)
```